# uses audit postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger, audit

I use the fork of audit trigger 91 plus :
https://github.com/iloveitaly/audit-trigger

but I don't understand why this command don't work

```
SELECT audit.audit_table('schema1.table1');
```

I search with ', ", combination of them... nothing.
It's the "schema_qualified" problem but how to resolve it ?